# Filter entities in Development console

Tags: java, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

To add some context I use [App Engine Java SDK](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/java/download):

- Run sever with `mvn appengine:devserver`
- Browse Datastore entities in `localhost:8080/_ah/admin`.

In Google Cloud Console the Datastore entities can be filtered by key; but when testing the application locally I didn't find a way to do so and have to skip through multiple pages.

Is there anything similar that I can use on the [Local Development Server](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/tools/using-local-server)?

Answer (score 0):

For any of you who are interested in development of this feature, there is [an issue](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/112127332) opened for this in the Google's Public Issue tracker.